# Linux Kernel dentry and inode

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to construct absolute path from the given dentry and inode?

Thanks all

Comment: Can you iteratively ascend `d_parent` and keep track of `d_name`?

Comment: yes it's possible, I've done that... *BUT* if the given dentry is a mounted filesystem (from USB, NFS or whatever else), the d_parent will stop until the root of that filesystem... suppose, /dev/sda1 is mounted at /tmp/a/b/c/d/e/(*root of /dev/sda1*), the most top d_parent value will be *after* "e" directory

Comment: @Billy Were you hoping for a different solution?

Comment: @Billy I see. Perhaps you'd have to check the `vfsmount`.

Comment: Do you want to handle chroot and privot root?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `struct path` (or can construct one), look at how tomoyo do this:
   http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/security/tomoyo/realpath.c#L86

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `dentry_path()`.  It will fill a buffer with the path up to the mount's root.  To keep going past there, you'll need iterate through your file's `f_vfsmount` and it's `mnt_parent`s until you reach the real root of the file system.

Answer (score 1):

yes, just one dentry is enough, back traversing through dentry->parent.
take care when you meet a mountpoint, for linux support "one dentry mounts multiple devices" ... well, it's easy to code,just switch to vfsmnt->mnt_parent .

BTW: i was often confused why linux builds the mountpoint-linklist with a field "mnt_parent" rather than "mnt_child", when writing this answer, i seemed to  guess out somthing.