# How do you get the struct file of the parent of another struct file in the Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

In the Linux Kernel: I have a file (ie, a 'struct file') of a directory.  Let's call it f_child.  I need a file reference for the parent directory.

I'm currently retrieving this like so:

1) Create a 'struct path' from the f_dentry->d_parent and f_vfsmnt of f_child.  I check, of course, that the d_parent is non-null.

2) Get the path (ie, a string, not a struct path... a char *) of the parent of f_child using d_path, passing in the path we retrieved from step 1.

3) Pass that string to filp_open, which returns the struct file * that I want.

It seems to work.  I'm worried though about the assumption I'm making at step 1 that the vfs mount of the parent and child will be the same.  Will that bite me at some point?  Is there a better way of doing this?  Clearly, I don't understand the vfs mount structure well enough.  Do all dentries belonging to the same super block have the same vfs mount?

btw: I anticipate, and a appreciate, the rebuke for opening a file in the Kernel, but what I'm doing really does require it. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this very helpful page:
http://kedar.dumpstack.com/pubs/al_vfsmounts.html

(Also posted here in case that goes away):
http://kerneltrap.org/node/3749

While short, this is valuable for anyone trying to begin to understand the workings of the vfs because it goes beyond describing the parts (superblock, inode, dentry, etc.) to describing how they work together to create the namespace users interact with.

Anyway, if I'm reading this correctly, a tree of dentries are rooted from a super block corresponding to a file system, not a vfsmount.  So I have to check to make sure that the d_parent and the dentry have the same vfs mount.  The `mnt_root` check I mention below accomplishes this.

So, it's not null I need to check at step 1 but these two things (I get this from the implementation of `__d_path` in [fs/dcache.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=2.6.32;i=__d_path)):

1. `mnt_root`.  If the f_dentry of f_child is the same as mnt_root of its f_vfsmnt, then I can't look at f_dentry->d_parent.  We're at the root of the mount.  If I want to go above that dentry, I have to move up the tree by looking at the dentry f_vfsmnt->mnt_mountpoint and the vfsmount f_vfsmnt->mnt_parent.
2. `IS_ROOT`.  `IS_ROOT` takes a dentry, and if it returns true, then there is no point looking above that.  We're at the root of the file system, which may not be the root of our namespace.

Now that I understand some more, I realize that the post by J-16 SDiZ is helpful:

[Linux Kernel dentry and inode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622812/linux-kernel-dentry-and-inode)

He references the tomoyo implementation of getting a real path:

http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/security/tomoyo/realpath.c#L86